# Can not arrange elements side by side

Tags: html, css

I'm scripting a little IMG Upload Website, and at my File viewer i really cant arrange the Elements side by side. I have tried flexbox, to float them, put them into a UL, but nothing worked...

Here is my whole Homepage, it is the uploads.php in the main directory: http://www.filedropper.com/imghost

My HTML + CSS: http://gruenlink.de/1aii

Database for Images:

Tablename = imglinks

Columns   = id, uid, imgname, link

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Show us your HTML and CSS, don't just paste a URL to your site. Although having looked through the HTML source of your site, I can see so many issues, I haven't seen a <font> or <center> tag in a long time

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the changes i did to your HTML/CSS

```
float: left
overflow: hidden
```

https://jsfiddle.net/90L2tzep/5/

Comment: Wow that looks pretty perfect! Could you please explain `overflow: hidden` ?

Thanks at all!

Comment: Sure, declaring overflow establishes a new block formatting context, which makes the div contains its children, otherwise the container ( in your case with a border ) height will be 0. Feel free to mark this as the correct answer, Thank you :)

Comment: When I apply your solution to my website it looks like this: http://epvpimg.com/ep8Tf :/ You know why it could be?

Comment: Have a look at the jsfiddle i linked, i changed some of the html markup as well and some more css changes.